# Javascript: Function within a function

Tags: javascript, function, var

**Is there any reason why this code isn't working?**
I have put the entire script into a function for the sake of the `playAgain` variable (see bottom) which would **restart** the function. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function headsTails() {
    var userChoice;
    userChoice = prompt('Heads or Tails');

    function myGame(heads,tails) {  
        var result;
        var coin;
        result = Math.random()
        if(result > 0.5) {
            coin = "heads";
        } else {
            coin = "tails";
        }
        if(userChoice === "heads") {
            if(coin = "heads") {
                alert("You win!");
            } else if(coin = "tails") {
                alert("You lose!");
            }
        }
        if(userChoice === "tails") {
            if(coin = "heads") {
                alert("You lose!");
            } else if(coin = "tails") {
                alert("You win!");
            }
        }
    }
    myGame();
    var playAgain;
    playAgain = confirm(Do you want to play again?)
    if(playAgain) {
        headsTails();
    } else {
        alert("Thanks for playing!")
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way is this not working? Also, _"Sorry about the messy spacing"_ -- really? Just fix it! It would make it less likely that someone capable of answering would simply move on without bothering.

Comment: Shouldn't `confirm(Do you want to play again?)` be `confirm('Do you want to play again?')`?

Comment: Formatting is important because it can help you realize why your code might not be working. Check it again after the reformatting and see if you can tell why it might not be doing what you expect.

Comment: In regards to spacing/formatting, http://jsbeautifier.org/ is great for formatting code before posting

Comment: I'm confused that you are using `===` in the conditions, immediately followed by `=` in the next condition.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you Ted Hopp, thanks darkajax, one of my many syntax errors, and also kinakuta and Ian, much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks also Felix King, what should I do to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have many syntax errors:

```
coin = "heads" -> coin === "heads"
coin = "tails" -> coin === "tails"
confirm(Do you want to play again ?) -> confirm("Do you want to play again ?")
```

*I would recommend reading about Javascript and in general about programming languages...*

Corrected headsTails function:

```
function headsTails() {
    var userChoice;
    userChoice = prompt('Heads or Tails');

    function myGame(heads, tails) {
        var result;
        var coin;
        result = Math.random();
        if (result > 0.5) {
            coin = "heads";
        } else {
            coin = "tails";
        }
        if (userChoice === "heads") {
            if (coin === "heads") {
                alert("You win!");
            } else if (coin === "tails") {
                alert("You lose!");
            }
        }
        if (userChoice === "tails") {
            if (coin === "heads") {
                alert("You lose!");
            } else if (coin === "tails") {
                alert("You win!");
            }
        }
    }

    myGame();
    var playAgain;
    playAgain = confirm("Do you want to play again ?")
    if (playAgain) {
        headsTails();
    } else {
        alert("Thanks for playing!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has solved all of my problems concerning the subject.